# Looking for inexpensive web content filtering options for home use

Tags: linux, firewall, parental-controls, wcf

I've been using an old Fortigate-60 at home for the kids for some time but now the license is expired again. Are there any free or inexpensive alternatives? I'd like something I can run on a linux firewall and share against multiple users, with different profiles. In the past I ran squid and I whitelisted sites each kid was allowed to use but this becomes tedious as the kids get older and need access to more. I'd love something that could check a website rating or category list, let the user through for certain categories, and block bad or unrated sites. I don't really need virus checking or email scanning or the like.

Comment: http://dansguardian.org/

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [OpenDNS](http://www.opendns.com/)? It even has a [Family Shield](http://www.opendns.com/familyshield) option. Simple to setup, no need to install or maintain anything on the computers, and works well.

If you're looking for a software based solution to allow more fine control over individual computers then why not just setup the hosts file or throw together some `ipfw` rules?